# HP ALM 12.53 - Dashboard on Sharepoint

Tags: hp-alm, sharepoint

We try to achieve a dynamic overview for our management according all HP ALM Projects on the SharePoint

What we got so far is the “Share Analysis Item” – link (“Copy Analysis Item Public URL” ) embed in the SharePoint.

But this creates just a graph from that point in time when the URL-link was copied. But what we do need is an URL which shows the actual state of the HP ALM progress. Otherwise we can just take screenshots.

Because I am not the SharePoint owner I am not sure now whether this problem is based on the way it was embedded in the SharePoint  or it is a problem within HPALM.

Does anyone have any experiences here?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I found this by myself
...
Yes, in Analysis view right click the report, select "Share Analysis item" and then choose if you want to share it via public URL (no authentication) or via authenticated URL. You can include the URL in your sharepoint page. It automatically displays the up to date report within your sharepoint page. I think this is available since version 11.
....
WebPart for SP 2016
•   Page Viewer Web part
•   height 400 & width 650

Just as a hint - the update happens every 60 min right now - so to check you have to wait
Thomas